# Unable to add data of one mongoose model into another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Newbie Dev here.

I have 2 schemas:

```
var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String 
});

var subCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    parent: {
        name: String,
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Parent'
        }
    }
});
```

I am making a seed file for testing purposes.
I first create all categories:

```
async function addCats() {
    try {
        for (const category of categories){
            await Category.create({name:category});
            console.log("Created Category: " + category)
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is afterwards creating the subcategories, all categories are created properly.

But then if I run:

```
async function addSubs(){
    try {

        for(const sub of sub_categories) {
            let foundParent = await Category.find({name: sub.parent});
            console.log('Parent: ' + foundParent);
            let createdSub = await SubCategory.create({name:sub.name, parent: foundParent});
            await console.log("Created sub-category: " + createdSub.name + " with parent: " + createdSub.parent + " parents ID is: " + createdSub.parent.id)
        }

    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I get

```
Parent: { _id: 5b474611e6eb361cd5d051cc, name: 'Men\'s', __v: 0 }
Created sub-category: Shirts with parent: {} parents ID is: undefined
```

It finds the right parent but even then it doesnt seem to put it into the subcategory as it is supposed to and I dont know why.

I also tried doing:

```
let createdSub = await SubCategory.create({name:sub.name, parent:{ name: foundParent.name, id: foundParent._id}});
```

But I get:

```
Created sub-category: Shirts with parent: {} parents ID is: undefined
```

parent is still an empty object in subcategory and IDK why id is undefined.

Been stuck all morning and still have more to this seed file.

Comment: Is the parent's id a `string` or `ObjectId`? you should check that, I see in your log it's a string but your schema specifies it as `ObjectId`

Comment: It should be an ObjectId, its not in the schema itself I am just relying on the ObjectId that mongo gives to all items.

Comment: You should clarify that, as I see it is printed as `string` in your log

Comment: How do you see it is a string? Could it be that it is being converted into a string?

Comment: I am not sure, that is why I think you should check it

Comment: It was an ObjectId I figured the problem out and put the answer bellow, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I remembered learning that x.find returns an array, so The foundParent variable which was being returned from the Category.find request I believe was in an array, I used Category.findOne and then I could access the variables this is my code:

```
for(const sub of sub_categories) {
            var foundParent = await Category.findOne({name: sub.parent});
            let newSub = {name:sub.name, parent: {name:foundParent.name, id: foundParent._id}};
            let createdSub = await SubCategory.create(newSub);
```

It was hard to spot because the parent variable was an object so when you printed out:

```
console.log(foundParent);
```

and got:

```
{ _id: 5b477ec9818a58240da721e5, name: 'Children\'s', __v: 0 }
```

It didnt seem like it was in an array.

I guess you could also take it out of the array and then access it but I wasn't sure how to.

Also a question I still remain with is even using findOne and getting foundParent outside of an array/accessable, if I try to do:

```
let newSub = {name:sub.name, parent: foundParent};
```

Then newSub.parent is also printed out as an empty object {} and newSub.parent.id or .name are undefined.

Thanks for the help and if anyone know the answer to that last question please let me know.